# Can dll built with VS2008 use dll built with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, com, mixing

I have a dll (DLL A) built with VS2010 that uses MFC and other dlls built with VS2010.
I have another dll (DLL B) which is built with VS2008 and run on an application which is again built with VS2008. DLL A imports DLLB (with #import directive) and creates com objects. The creation of the objects itself succeeds however the application crashes somewhere. I think it crashes at the time of displaying the controls (these are just assumptions). The thing is I don`t have the source for the application. DLL A is just a plug in to that application.
The question is, is there anything to be considered when doing such mix? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be fine to call code across the DLL boundary *if* you use C linkage, ie. if the DLL boundary is using primitive C types like char* and int. If you're passing C++ references/pointers across the DLL boundary,  you should really build both sides with the same compiler flags and the same compiler. There's no guarantee for example that the VS2010 compiler will layout memory for a class object in exactly the same way as the VS2008 compiler Although if you use the same byte alignment flags, the layout will most likely be the same, you can't guarantee it.

Comment: all the parameters that go into/come out from DLL A are com objects exposed in DLL A

Comment: In that case, since you're using COM, there's no reason why each side of the dll boundary should not be using different compilers.